# Query derivation mechanism in Spring Data Couchbase 4.0.0

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-couchbase

I am currently upgrading a project with Spring data couchbase from 3.x.x to 4.0.0.
I am experiencing a problem with Query derivation mechanism. Spring-data-couchbase is trying to generate queries even if i have a not empty @Query on repositories methods.

For example,with this repository :

```
public interface CategoryRepository extends CouchbaseRepository<CategoryEntity, String> {
    
   @Query("#{#n1ql.selectEntity} WHERE #{#n1ql.filter} AND type = $1")
   List<CategoryEntity> anyMethodName(String type);
}
```

When using this repository, i have an exception :

```
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property anyMethodName found for type CategoryEntity.
```

When i debug this error, i found spring-data trying to generate a Query using the name of method.

Do you have idea about this problem? How can i disable the generation query mechanism ?

Answer (score 1):

this bug seems to be solved in the latest fix Release 4.0.1